# Stop getting Git tags from specific remote repo

Tags: git, version-control, version, githooks, git-flow

**Question:** Is it possible to not fetch tags by default by using `git fetch Repo1` instead of having to use `--no-tags`?

**Software:**

- Git
- [Git Flow](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow)
- [Git Flow Hooks](https://github.com/jaspernbrouwer/git-flow-hooks)

  - Automatically bump versions when starting a release or hotfix. Versions are generated, written to file and committed.
  - Automatically specify tag messages.
- [Tower App for Mac OS X](http://www.git-tower.com)

**Description:** I have two repositories, Repo1 and Repo2. Both Repo's use tags to label versions (v0.0.1) but the versions are completely different from each other.

`git fetch Repo1` automatically gets the tags from the repository but I need it to stop getting the tags from Repo1 because it's causing problems with Git Flow Hooks. I know I can use `git fetch Repo1 --no-tags` but I am using the Tower app instead of command line and it's set to fetch every 30 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `.gitconfig`, specify `remote.remote-name.tagopt`. From the `git-config` man page:

```
   remote.<name>.tagopt
       Setting this value to --no-tags disables automatic tag following when fetching from remote <name>. Setting it to --tags will fetch every tag from remote <name>,
       even if they are not reachable from remote branch heads. Passing these flags directly to git-fetch(1) can override this setting. See options --tags and --no-tags of
       git-fetch(1).
```